# Expo Publish not updating React Native App

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

We've created a webview app and we are using Expo RN. We have done EAS Build -p ios & EAS Submit -p ios.

We have then submitted it to the app store and it is now live on the app store.

But when we make a change with the app, and run Expo Publish, the app doesn't update. I've read so many docs but I'm struggling to see what I've missed.

Any help would be great!

Eas.json

```
{

 "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.41.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide us with your eas.json (remove any sensitive info of course).

Comment: I've updated the post with our Eas.json file

Comment: @Phobos Any help?

Comment: Any update on this I have the same issue. @Phobos any help would be much appreciated.